# Package is not executing while using cursor input

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**I have created a Package from existing procedure , procedure only is giving exact output  but while creating package there is no errors but it is not showing the output file  that i passed to be input in cursor**

---

### ------------------PACKAGE AS FOLLOW-------------------------

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE user.report AS
    PROCEDURE distribution (
        code_in   IN             user.test.schm_code%TYPE,
        fromdate       IN             DATE,
        todate         IN             DATE
    );

END report;
/
-------------------------------------------------
----------------Package Body---------------------
-------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY user.report as
----------------------------------------------
----------VARIABLE DECLARATION----------------
----------------------------------------------

    code_in             user.test.code%TYPE;
    fromdate                 DATE;
    todate                   DATE;
    v_code              user.test.code%TYPE;    
    v_count                 number;
    v_code          user.test.acct_crncy_code%TYPE;
    v_amount        number(17,4);
-----------------------------------------------
---------------CURSOR DECLARATION--------------
-----------------------------------------------


CURSOR td_data IS
    ( SELECT
        test.code,
        COUNT(test.code) AS count,
        test.crncy
    FROM
        user.table1
        JOIN user.test ON test.id = table1.id
    WHERE
        user.test.opendate BETWEEN TO_DATE(fromdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE(todate, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        and
        user.test.code = code_in
    GROUP BY
        test.code,test.crncy
    );

------------------------PROCEDURE CREATION-----------------------    
PROCEDURE distribution 
(
    code_in   IN             user.test.code%TYPE,
    fromdate       IN          DATE,
    todate         IN          DATE
)
AS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('code'||'    '||'COUNT'||'       '||'TOTAL');
    OPEN td_data;
    LOOP
        FETCH td_data INTO v_code,v_count,v_code,v_amount;
        EXIT WHEN td_data%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_code
                             || '             '
                             ||v_count
                             || '                '
                             ||v_code
                             ||' '
                             ||v_amount
                             );

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE td_data;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END distribution;
END report;
/
BEGIN
user.report.distribution('x1fsr','01-02-2016','01-07-2020');
END;
/

alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yyyy';
```

I have tried creating package without cursor working fine 
I have tried creating cursor without user input workking fine but with user input it is not working properly

Answer (score 2):

Variables you used were not initialized so cursor didn't fetch anything. That's because you declared it (as well as bunch of variables) *globally* (for the whole package body), not locally (for the procedure, while you're passing parameters to a procedure and never passed any of them to cursor. If you insist, create a parametrized cursor).

Also, you've declared `V_CODE` twice; why?

Anyway: I'd suggest you to do it this way:

- use a cursor `FOR` loop as it is easier to maintain (you don't have to open, fetch, exit, close - Oracle does that for you)
- don't declare any additional variables - use implicit cursor variables
- remove such an exception handler, it does no good at all as you aren't handling anything. If you called the procedure from some front-end application (such as Apex or Forms) and something ("others", eh?) happens, you wouldn't see anything as `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` doesn't work there
- as `fromdate` and `todate` are `DATE`s, no need to `TO_DATE` them

OK, here you go:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY USER.report
AS
   PROCEDURE distribution (code_in   IN USER.test.code%TYPE,
                           fromdate  IN DATE,
                           todate    IN DATE)
   AS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'code' || '    ' || 'COUNT' || '       ' || 'TOTAL');

      FOR cur_r
         IN (  SELECT test.code, COUNT (test.code) AS COUNT, test.crncy
                 FROM USER.table1 JOIN USER.test ON test.id = table1.id
                WHERE     USER.test.opendate BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
                      AND USER.test.code = code_in
             GROUP BY test.code, test.crncy)
      LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               v_code
            || '             '
            || cur_r.code
            || '                '
            || cur_r.COUNT
            || ' '
            || cur_r.crncy);
      END LOOP;
   END distribution;
END report;
```

Comment: That means for cursor also i can give input to the cursor of declared variables done !!!!  **Thank You**